# can we use visual icon like arrow mark in Jenkins stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

when moving from one stage to another , instead of asking yes or no or password to proceed to next stage in Jenkins. can we have visual icon like arrow mark ?

so that after clicking in the arrow mark , it should proceed further steps.

i am expecting some icon between 2nd and 3rd stage. only if i click it should move further